# C# DirectShow / Direct X

Tags: c#, directx, directshow

My C# application uses DirectShow and requires DirectX to run. I would like check that DirectX is enabled at start-up, can anyone advise the correct method to do so?

Thanks

Comment: You can disable DirectX? Are you sure? I think DirectX 8 or better should be present on all computers with Windows XP or better.

Comment: On my XP machine I can open dxdiag and disable DirectX features DirectDraw Acceleration and Direct3D Acceleration. I cannot do this on my Win 7 machine, I think it may depend on what graphics chip you have.

Comment: And does that actually disable DirectDraw or Direct3D? Or does it just disable hardware acceleration, as the text suggests it would? (I.e. it will still run, only slower.)

Answer (score 1):

DirectShow is not a part of DirectX. There is only some intersection in video renderer using DirectDraw and Direct3D, and wrappers over audio APIs which are in fact no longer independent but wrappers over other APIs. I would say there is nothing to check for and DirectShow is already an OS core component, but if you have some specific concerns then what are they? Maybe you could attempt to create some DirectX object directly on app startup and see if this attempt is successful.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm right in saying if the DirectX DLLs aren't installed on the host machine, your application wont even start.  Beyond that, you should always be checking that creation of DirectX objects succeeds before attempting to use them.